# How to expose two graphql endpoints using Netflix Dgs one public and the other private in springboot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, netflix-dgs

How can I expose two api endpoints in graphql one private and another public, where the public will not need authentication and just be accessed from anywhere, or how can I make some queries public and others public, my current implementation all queries and mutations are private meaning they wouldn't want to be authenticated, am using Netflix dgs any help towards the right direction I will appreciate.